# Find object using string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Is there some way in Visual Basic/Studio to find an object using a string?

I want to use it so that i can find objects by concatenating a variable with it.

Something along the lines of:

```
[Variable & "Main"].Visible = true
```

Just to elaborate, I don't want to use a table that iterates through all the objects in the form.

This is in VB.net. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way

```
Me.Controls(Variable & "Main").Visible = true
```

See [Control.Controls property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any official posting from a Microsoft website, but in my experience this is not possible.  I would equate it to trying to use a string as a table name in SQL Server.  One option is that you could iterate through the controls on the page (I'm guessing by the `.Visible = true` that you are dealing with controls) and look for a matching control ID.  If found you will then have access to the properties for that control.  Let me know if you would like to see an example.  I'm not at a pc with Visual Studio so it would not be until tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm fine without the program, but thank you very much for answering! I guess iteration is the only way to go, huh? :)

Comment: As far as I know. I'm not the most experienced programmer though so someone else might be able to shed some light. If anything else comes to mind I'll let ya know!

Comment: In SQL server queries, table names are exclusively strings.

Comment: @DanVerdolino, I was afraid I wasn't being clear enough - sorry for the confusion.  This is what I meant by you can't use a string (should have been more clear that I meant a string-like data type):

Comment: `--works

select *
from TableName

--doesn't work

declare @Table1 varchar(6)
set @Table1 = "TableName"

select *
from @Table1` -I'm still getting used to the formatting of the comments so bare with me as I had to use two separate comments.